# Symfony2 Perform an action after sending the answer in the controller

Tags: symfony, controller

i would like to perform an action in my controller but after i rendered the view to the user here is my controller action

```
public function addAction(Request $request)
{
    $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('ROLE_ADMIN', null, 'Vous n\'avez pas les droits pour accéder à cette page' );
    $preconisation = new Preconisation();
    $form = $this->createForm(new PreconisationType($preconisation), $preconisation);

    if($request->isMethod('POST')) {
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $rapport = $em->getRepository('DataBaseBundle:rapport')->findByIdRapport($preconisation->getRapport()->getIdRapport());
            $rapport[0]->incPreco($preconisation->getRapport()->getIdRapport());
            $em->persist($preconisation);
            $em->persist($rapport[0]);
            $em->flush();
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('data_base_preconisation_index'));
        }
    }
    return $this->render('DataBaseBundle:Preconisation:add.thml.twig', array('form' => $form->createView(),'menu' => 1,
        'leftMenu' => 1,));
}
```

So

i would like to perform this after the user has receive his answer to avoid a long charging time

```
$rapport = $em->getRepository('DataBaseBundle:rapport')->findByIdRapport($preconisation->getRapport()->getIdRapport());
                $rapport[0]->incPreco($preconisation->getRapport()->getIdRapport());
                $em->persist($rapport[0]);
```

i saw that I could use listener and dispatcher but i don't really understand his structure or how it works. But i also saw the httpKernel with the terminate event. Unfortunately i don't have answer. I don't know which one is the best...

Any advice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A listener is a good way to structure your code, but it won't speed up your application. If you want to execute code after sending a Response to the user, you'll have to use a cron job or job scheduler.

I can recommend using [JMSJobQueueBundle](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSJobQueueBundle) ([documentation](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSJobQueueBundle)). In short, this is what to do:

1. Create a console command you handle the action you want;
2. Use your controller, listener, or whatever to [create a job](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSJobQueueBundle/master/usage):

`$job = new Job('my-symfony2:command', array('some-args', 'or', '--options="foo"'));`

Comment: And do you know where i can find an example of use of listener of a symfony 2.8 app ? cause on the cookbook it's not really easy to understand the structure of it.

Answer (score 1):

After sending the response/view, you can call (from the view) a distant php script using javascript and ajax mecanism

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to add a listener to the event "[kernel.terminate](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_kernel/introduction.html#the-kernel-terminate-event)" (only if the treatment doesn't alter the response).